# URL rewriting through .htaccess is not working properly

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a .htaccess which reads as follows

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\-]+) /index.php?page_name=$1 [L]
```

I want the link 
`http://www.solublesilicates.com/our-services` when clicked should read as `http://www.solublesilicates.com/?page_name=our-services`. 
Please do help.

Comment: Do you have any error?

Answer (score 2):

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\-]+)$ /index.php?page_name=$1 [L, QSA]
```

Just change it to the above. Should work perfectly.

Comment: this solution is givinmg 500 Internal Server Error.

Comment: My site url structure is www.solublesilicates.com/our-services and in the php code it should appear as www.solublesilicates.com/?page_name=our-services.

Comment: I have made the following changes 
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\-]+)$ /?page_name=$1 [L,QSA]. It is showing the pages but if I try to retrieve the page_name parameter through request by doing $_REQUEST['page_name'] I am not getting any value.

Answer (score 1):

You have error in your syntax. Your regex should end with $ sign

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\-]+)$ /index.php?page_name=$1 [L]
```

Comment: You can see in this article $ is necessary to mark the end of the string

https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204643270/using-htaccess-rewrite-rules

Comment: Yes, you are right, but the $ is optional in rewriteRule pattern. You can try the code on your server to see this.

Comment: thanks to all.it is wporking now.I have the following changes RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\-]+)$ /?page_name=$1 [L]

Answer (score 1):

Change the Rewrite Rule to

`RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)  index.php?page_name=$1 [L,QSA]`

Comment: not working. My site url structure is www.solublesilicates.com/our-services and in the php code it should appear as www.solublesilicates.com/?page_name=our-services.